# Find first specific HTML tag above the found selection - Python / BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have an events table in the following format

```
<table class="events">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td"><span class="event_date">28.02.2018</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="event">
        <td class="event_time">18:00</td>
        <td class="event_name">Event_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="event">
        <td class="event_time">19:00</td>
        <td class="event_name">Event_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td"><span class="event_date">01.03.2018</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="event">
        <td class="event_time">18:00</td>
        <td class="event_name">Event_3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="event">
        <td class="event_time">19:00</td>
        <td class="event_name">Event_4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="event">
        <td class="event_time">20:00</td>
        <td class="event_name">Event_5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am able to extract the time and the name easily for each event with following commands

```
event_container = page_soup.findAll("tr", {"class":"event"})

for event in event_container:
    event_name = event.find("td", {"class":"event_name"})
    event_time = event.find("td", {"class":"event_time"})
```

However I'm just not able to assign the event_date correctly to those events

Wanted output

> Name: Event_1, Date: 28.02.2018, Time: 18:00
>
> Name: Event_2, Date: 28.02.2018, Time: 19:00
>
> Name: Event_3, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 18:00
>
> Name: Event_4, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 19:00
>
> Name: Event_5, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 20:00

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is that iterate over all the `<tr>` tags and check if it has a `<span>` tag with the date or not. If it has the date, update the date else get name and time.

But in Python, it is [EAFP](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html) (easier to ask for forgiveness than permission). So, you could simply use this:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='events')
event_date = ''
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    try:
        event_date = row.td.span.text
        continue
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    event_name = row.find('td', class_='event_name').text
    event_time = row.find('td', class_='event_time').text
    print('Name: {}, Date: {}, Time: {}'.format(event_name, event_date, event_time))
```

Output:

```
Name: Event_1, Date: 28.02.2018, Time: 18:00
Name: Event_2, Date: 28.02.2018, Time: 19:00
Name: Event_3, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 18:00
Name: Event_4, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 19:00
Name: Event_5, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 20:00
```

Comment: Thank you - this was the solution I was looking for! Just couldn't figure out the for loop on my own.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to scrape all the desired text, and then group under the appropriate event date:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import itertools, re
def beautify(f):
   def wrapper():
      return ["Name: {name}, Date: {date}, Time: {time}".format(**dict(zip(['date', 'time', 'name'], i))) for i in f()]
   return wrapper

@beautify
def raw_data():
   s = soup(data, 'lxml')
   final_data = [i.text for i in s.find_all('td')]
   final_results = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(final_data, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+$', x)))]
   new_final_data = [[a+b[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(b), 2)] for a, b in [final_results[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(final_results), 2)]]
   return [i for b in new_final_data for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['Name: Event_1, Date: 28.02.2018, Time: 18:00', 'Name: Event_2, Date: 28.02.2018, Time: 19:00', 'Name: Event_3, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 18:00', 'Name: Event_4, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 19:00', 'Name: Event_5, Date: 01.03.2018, Time: 20:00']
```